# Force pod creation order

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there some way to force pod creation order on Kubernetes?

I have a scenario where Kubernetes are selecting a node pool with few resources and the first pod to be deployed consume a very small resource, but the next one consumes a lot of resources and the deployment fails.

So I was wondering if there is a way to instruct Kubernetes to deploy first the pod that is resource hog then the small ones

Comment: That's usually the problem a `StatefulSet` is designed to accomplish, even in cases where it doesn't actually have any "state"; although you may very well have an X-Y problem going on, it's hard to tell from the amount of details in your question

Comment: @Rodrigo : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: No. It wasn't. What we did was upgrade the Kubernetes version to the latest stable, and we are seeing fewer or no more issues, but I can not guarantee that is the solution